# Convert instance name in SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I use a VM with a fresh installed SQL Server 2022 Express. Also installed latest SSMS 19.
Normally I can refer to local databases as localhost. But it is not available.
The only way to access local databases is through localhost\SQLEXPRESS.
This don't work as I am member in a team and we share same config-files in github for our local databases.

Is there a way to convert from localhost\SQLEXPRESS to localhost ?

Comment: Express doesn't run on the default port by default; it's a named instance. You'd have to override the name and port defaults.

Comment: The SQL Server is a named instance (`localhost\SQLEXPRESS`) and I don't think you can change the SQL Server instance to default instance. However, during Express installation, there is an option for you to specify to use default instance. Meaning, you will need to reinstall if you wish to change from named to default instance

Comment: Why, out of interest, are you oposed to the instance being named?

Answer (score 1):

If you have administrative privilege open the S**QL Server Configuration Manager** then:

SQL Server Network Configuration >
Protocols for SQLEXPRESS >

[image]

Right click o TCP/IP and make sure in IP Addresses tab , scroll down to **IPAll** and make sure the TCP port is empty. Empty port means default port (1433)> After restarting sql server, you can connect to **localhost** instead of **localhost\SQLEXPRES**

[image]